# jQuery show hide multiple Div not work in action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this jQuery code for show/hide multiple div in my page:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#toggle').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $(target).toggleClass('hidden show');
    });
});
```

```html
<span class="add-btn">
    <a href="#options" id="toggle">
        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
            Filter
        </span>
    </a>
</span>
<div id="options" class="well hidden">hehe</div>    
<span class="add-btn">
    <a href="#options2" id="toggle">
        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
            Filter2
        </span>
    </a>
</span>
<div id="options2" class="well hidden">hoho</div>
```

```css
.show {
    display: block !important;
}
.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

But in Action Not work! how do fix this?!

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/coov8tet/)

Comment: Your fiddle and included code was missing a closing `});` - if you put that in [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/coov8tet/2/) (Note: `id` should be unique)

Comment: just a syntax error - check here: https://jsfiddle.net/coov8tet/3/

Comment: @Jamiec: u click in Both?! filter2 not work in action

Comment: @NewCod3r thats reusing the same id - if you target just the `a` or indeed a shared `class` then it works - https://jsfiddle.net/coov8tet/4/ (targets `a`) or https://jsfiddle.net/coov8tet/5/ (targets shared `class`)

Comment: Vote to close as typographycal error (yeah, it's offtopic in stackoverflow, just read the rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `id` triggers unique identifiers, they can't be the same. The code will only evaluate the first instance and ignore any others.

```
$(function() {

       $('#toggle1, #toggle2').click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var target = $(this).attr('href');
         $(target).toggleClass('hidden show');
       });
});
```

**Example:**

```js
 $(function() {

       $('#toggle1, #toggle2').click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var target = $(this).attr('href');
         $(target).toggleClass('hidden show');
       });
});
```

```css
.show {
    display: block !important;
}
.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="add-btn"><a href="#options" id="toggle1">
              <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i>Filter</span></a>
</span>



<div id="options" class="well hidden">hehe</div>

<span class="add-btn"><a href="#options2" id="toggle2">
              <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i>Filter2</span></a>
</span>



<div id="options2" class="well hidden">hoho</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign the same id, use class instead:

HTML

```
<span class="add-btn"><a href="#options" class="toggle">
          <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-filter">     </i>Filter</span></a>
 </span>

<div id="options" class="well hidden">hehe</div>

<span class="add-btn"><a href="#options2" class="toggle">
          <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-filter">     </i>Filter2</span></a>
</span>

<div id="options2" class="well hidden">hoho</div>
```

JS

```
 $(function() {

   $('.toggle').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var target = $(this).attr('href');
     $(target).toggleClass('hidden show');
   });
})
```

CSS

```
.show {
    display: block !important;
}
.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```